# How to display exam page according to user's branch?

Tags: php, html

I want to display question papers according to student's branch.
I create 5 tables in database "aptitude".
tables are as following:
itque,
etrxque,
extcque,
civilque,
mechque.

branch name is store in 'register' database.

**If student is in IT department then only IT's question paper should display.**

but there is some problem in logic. question paper is not displayed according to the student's branch.

code of test.php:

```
<html>
    <body>
<?php
      require_once('appvars.php');
      require_once('connectvars.php');

      // Make sure the user is logged in before going any further.
      if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        echo '<span style="color:#FFF;text-align:center;"><p class="login">Please <a href="login.php"style="color: #FFFFFF">log in</a> to access this page.</p></span>';
        exit();
      }
      else {
        include("menu.php");
      }
      ?>
      <?php
     $dbc=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","register");
        $query = "SELECT branch FROM user WHERE m_id = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";
        $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
       if ($row != NULL) {
          $Branch = $row['branch'];

        }
        else {
          echo '<p class="error">There was a problem .</p>';
        }



      ?>
      <form action="./result.php" method="post">

    <?php

    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost" ,"root","");

    mysql_select_db("aptitude");



    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$Branch` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10 ");




     while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)):

        $q = $rows['Q_no'];
        $qus = $rows['Question'];
        $a = $rows['answer1'];
        $b = $rows['answer2'];
        $c = $rows['answer3'];
        $d = $rows['answer4'];
        $ans = $rows['correct'];
        echo" <p>&nbsp;</p>";
        echo "<p>Q:-&nbsp;$qus <br></p>";
        echo "<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;A <input type=radio name = 'answer[$q]' value = '$a'></input>$a &nbsp &nbsp<br>
    "; 
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;B <input type=radio name = 'answer[$q]' value = '$b'></input>$b &nbsp &nbsp<br>
    "; 
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;C <input type=radio name = 'answer[$q]' value = '$c'></input>$c &nbsp &nbsp<br>
     "; 
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;D <input type=radio name = 'answer[$q]' value = '$d'></input>$d <br><br> </p>";


        endwhile;
    ?>

    <center><input name="cmdSubmit" type="submit" id="cmdSubmit" value="Submit"/>
    </center>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Warning: using this code, I could look at any user's data! Worse, I could delete all user data by setting my cookie to `user_id='; DELETE FROM user; -- `. Cookie data is stored on the browser side; anyone with a text editor can change it!

Comment: try to debug your code with echo statements.

Comment: this code is not final program

Comment: this is raw code. I will make this changes in future.
my question is How to display exam page according to user's branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

required small changes

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$branch." ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10 ");
```

Comment: Also placing the curly braces around the variable would have worked (as I suggested previously)

Answer (score 0):

The biggest logic flaw is that if user_id isn't in the session and the user_id isn't in a cookie then you still allow processing to continue. You should force the user to login again.

Apache has the default session time of 20 minutes so you might want to increase the time to allow the students to complete the assessment otherwise when they come to save their answers there will be a server time out and no data saved.

Comment: my question is How to display exam page according to user's branch?

Comment: Are you sure that the user_id is set. Try echo $_SESSION['user_id']." ".$Branch just before the $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$Branch`  line. What is it reporting.

Comment: Place a var_dump( $query ); between $query = mysql_query("SELECT and the while statement. What is being returned? You might also want to change: "SELECT * FROM `{$Branch}` ORDER

Comment: no progress 
now this show 'boolean false' in o/p page including old o/p.
is there any way to choose branch automatically from logined user.
i give branch value of logined user to the $Branch and want to select that branch table.
the branch name and branch table names are same.

Comment: Now change the var_dump to var_dump($connect, $query). What does it return?

Comment: $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$branch." ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10 ");

work perfectly.